# How to convert serverless EVENT to types.Update in aiogram 3

Tags: telegram-bot, serverless, pydantic, aiogram

I use serverles architecture to run my telegram bot
I would like to understand how I can catch a user event and turn the caught event into an object of type types.Update

```
async def handler(event, context):
    await process_event(event, dp)
    return {'statusCode': 200, 'body': 'ok'}

async def process_event(event, dp: Dispatcher):
    update = json.loads(event['body'])
    bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
    update = types.Update(event)
    await dp.feed_update(bot, update)
```

```
{
  "errorMessage": "__init__() takes exactly 1 positional argument (2 given)",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/function/runtime/runtime.py\", line 193, in handle_event\n    result = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(result)\n",
    "  File \"/function/runtime/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py\", line 647, in run_until_complete\n    return future.result()\n",
    "  File \"/function/code/main.py\", line 44, in handler\n    await process_event(event, dp)\n",
    "  File \"/function/code/main.py\", line 39, in process_event\n    update = types.Update(event)\n",
    "  File \"pydantic/main.py\", line 332, in  pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__\n    def __init__(__pydantic_self__, **data: Any) -> None:\n"
  ]
}
```

I expect my bot to start working on a server architecture

Answer (score 0):

```
async def process_event(event, dp: Dispatcher):
    update = json.loads(event['body'])
    bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
    update = types.Update.parse_obj(update)
    await dp.feed_update(bot, update)


async def handler(event, context):
    await process_event(event, dp)
    return {'statusCode': 200, 'body': 'ok'}

# Parse json to Update with pydantic 
update = types.Update.parse_obj(update)
```